# URL Parameter in GET Route Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes

I have a route in `api.php` which look like this

```
Route::get('auth/logout/{token}', 'UserController@logout');
```

Then, I used Postman to check this API endpoint like this:

`localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/logout?token=$2y$10$InjSk8VExH76wSyA3OE9a.jhR/3GhAkJdBE3EyQ3O.Z0kCe/r7wp`y

But I just get a blank response in postman. It should show the message response and delete the data in the database. But it doesn't. Here is my `logout()` in `UserController.php`

```
public function logout($token){
    $current_token = Token::where('token', $token)->first();
    if($current_token){
        if(Token::where('token','=',$current_token)->delete()){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Logout Success'
            ], 201);
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized User'
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help my problem? I appreciate all of your approaches.

Edit...

When I send the dummy request like this and use `dd($token)`, Postman gives me `"asdfasdf"`.

```
localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/logout/asdfasdf
```

So, how do I send the `token` parameter in the URL using `"?"`

Edit 2...

I generate the token from bcrypted `user_id` from the database. In my case, I don't use any token generator plugin, or something else.

Comment: There are 3 places this function could end up. Only 2 of them return anything.

Comment: @miken32 do you mean I have to add another `else{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I finally know the reason why does the response in Postman is blank. `UserController.php` is a resource controller, but I added a custom `login()` method inside it. I should put the `Route` for the custom method above the `route` for the `resource` controller. It should look like this:

`Route::get('auth/login','UserController@login');`

`Route::resource('auth', 'UserController');`

Answer (score 0):

You have passed token with `/` in route and that is why you have had returns blank response.

As you said last in your question to pass token like `?` .
So you need pass token in **header**. 
In postman header section you have to pass key and value. 
Your key is **token** . Value is your token like `2y$10$InjSk8VExH76wSyA3OE9a.jhR/3GhAkJdBE3EyQ3O.Z0kCe/r7wpy`.

Read this doc: 
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/

For laravel api_ token:

Take a look with laravel official doc:https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication

Comment: Thanks for your approach. I've tried it. At first, in Postman, I used **Params** tab and send **token** as **Key** and **$2y$10$InjSk8VExH76wSyA3OE9a.jhR/3GhAkJdBE3EyQ3O.Z0kCe/r7wpy** as **Value**. Then, in URL it shows **host/api/v1/auth/logout?token=_token_**. But when I used **Header** tab in Postman as you said, the URL is only `host/api/v1/auth/logout`, and idk why it still returns a blank page. Did I do anything wrong? Thanks once again.

Comment: @DaniFadli Yes, when you have used the `header` tab then header value not shows on URL. So as your requirement `params` tab is ok.